# Multiple buttons having the same internal ID

Tags: source-engine

I recently bought a Logitech M705 mouse. It has 5 additional buttons (Tilt wheel left/right, and three thumb buttons)
However, the tilt wheel left and two of the thumb buttons show up as "MOUSE4" in Source games (I tried it with TF2) and the remaining two buttons show up as "MOUSE5". Is there any way to "separate" them?

EDIT: And if it matters, I am playing on Linux.

M705:[image: img]

Comment: If this were Windows, i would tell you to install the Logitech gaming framework, but I am not sure if it is available on Linux.

Comment: Does that fix the issue on Windows?

Comment: Or is this not present at all on Windows?

Comment: On Windows, most mouse buttons are not recognized beyond the basic LMB,  RMB and MMB and MAYBE mouse 4 and 5. For example,  I have been using logitech gaming mice for a few years now and for the extra buttons to work, I often first have to install the Logitech framework so they are recognised as buttons, then rebind them to modified function keys using the framework. I am not sure how good Linux is at mice with extra buttons.

Comment: There probably exists a virtual input device driver for this but apparently this is really a limitation of the Source Engine, it only supports max. 5 mouse buttons.

Comment: What version of Linux are you using? You'll have to install the right daemon from your repo according to https://forums.logitech.com/t5/Logitech-G-Keyboards/Logitech-Gaming-Software-on-Linux-Ubuntu/td-p/1239314

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux. The link didn't have any related entries to the mouse (or I might have missed it)

Comment: But it does mention to look in your distro software repo. Fortunately, Arch Linux has the most Logitech support.

Comment: Well, for what? g15daemon doesn't support this mouse. I installed it anyway without any luck. I think the real problem is that the Source Engine doesn't support more than 5 mouse buttons (see http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/540742667791895483/) A virtual joystick device that can be controlled by mouse buttons would be ideal but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: I didn't tell you to install the G15daemon, I told you to install the RIGHT daemon. There is probably another daemon that supports it better. If you want to use your buttons accurately in the source engine, you'll need to use a software or driver related way to rebind them to a key combination (usually using modifier keys) that the Source engine DOES support. I had to do the same thing on my own Windows machine, through the Logitech gaming framework. Check the Arch Linux wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/), a lot is explained on there.

Comment: "software or driver related way to rebind them to a key combination" - You mean something like xbindkeys? http://blog.hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/

Comment: Yes, exactly. The Logitech Gaming Framework provides that functionality by default, but you can use xbindkeys for it as well on Linux.

Comment: I will use this, but a virtual joystick device would be more beneficial as it wouldn't interfere with any keyboard actions.

Comment: Damn it. It works in the chat window, but not controlling anything in game. I don't know why. Here is my .xbindkeysrc; http://pastebin.com/qreCnd6M